# What kind of adhesive could I use as a binding agent for calcium chloride?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to create a paper-thin layer of calcium chloride. This sheet should still be capable of absorbing water and allowing gas to permeate downward when it becomes saturated with water and is exposed to sunlight on the top surface. I've tried a sandwich of a regular plastic sheet (top surface) and a gas-permeable membrane PDMS (bottom surface), with a layer of salt bound with commercial white glue between them. Unfortunately, the glue prevents any gas from reaching the bottom surface.

I wonder what I should use as a binding agent for my salty sheet while maintaining its water absorption and gas permeability capability.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but this is unlikely to work if exposed to ambient air, except perhaps atop an arid mountain. $\ce{CaCl2}$ is sufficiently [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy) that it dissolves in the water absorbed, i.e., [deliquesces](https://www.britannica.com/science/deliquescence). Even if the adhesive were porous but yet able to hold onto the resultant solution, the droplets would plug the pores of a membrane.

Try [another desiccant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_desiccants) (water absorbent) that does not deliquesce, such as anhydrous calcium sulfate, $\ce{CaSO4}$, sold with water indicator as [Drierite](https://secure.drierite.com/).

Some [SWAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess):

- For adhesive, you might try gelatin, as used in [photographic emulsions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_film), which allows water to permeate.
- Cellulose membrane (sold as [dialysis tubing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialysis_(chemistry))) is water-permeable and might be used to retain the desiccant.